# SSRS - Snowflake - Pass Date Variables or Parameters

Tags: reporting-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, ssrs-2012

In SSRS, I am using the Snowflake ODBC Driver to configure a Datasource to connect to a Snowflake Database.

In my SSRS Dataset, I have declared two Date variables and assigned Date Literals to each one:

```
Set StartDate = '2023-04-01';    
Set EndDate   = '2023-07-31';
```

... but SSRS throws the following error with those two lines:

```
Could not create a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the query and that your query syntax is correct.

ERROR [0A000] Actual statement count 3 did not match the desired statement count 1.
```

My intention was to use the following where clause in the body of the SQL.

```
Where ENCOUNTERDATE >= $StartDate And EncounterDate <= $EndDate
```

This works in Snowflake but SSRS doesn't even accept the Set StartDate and Set EndDate statements.

The SQL works fine if I just use Date literals in the Where Statement like this:

`Where ENCOUNTERDATE >=  '2023-07-01' And EncounterDate <=  '2023-07-31'`

I would appreciate some pointers/tips on how to pass Dates in SSRS to my Snowflake SQL.

Comment: Your dataset query is not returning anything, it's simply setting some variables that are only within the scope of the query when it runs. You'll need to set two parameters to the values you want then use ? in your query. If you write the query first the SSRS parameters will be created automatically I think. I don't use snowflake so this is just what I could find. Check out this for a working example. https://medium.com/@gabriel.mullen/snowflake-ssrs-parameters-a7bcc287fd07